# Redis backplane for ASP.NET C# SignalR sometime RedisTimeoutException

Tags: c#, asp.net, redis

I used redis backplance for ASP.NET, C#, SignalR, but sometimes it throws an exception:

> Exception information:
>
> Exception type: RedisTimeoutException
> Exception message: Timeout awaiting response (outbound=4KiB, inbound=0KiB, 5093ms elapsed, timeout is 5000ms), command=EVAL, next: EVAL, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 8, aw: False, bw: Inactive, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 0, in-pipe: 0, out-pipe: 0, last-in: 0, cur-in: 0, sync-ops: 0, async-ops: 18240, serverEndpoint: x.x.x.x:6379, conn-sec: 26633.92, aoc: 0, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: WIN-VNHOF53GPT5(SE.Redis-v2.7.4.20928), IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=33,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=32766,Min=33,Max=32767), v: 2.7.4.20928 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts: https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
>
> Request information:
> Request URL: [http://x.xxxx.xx/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=ype2eE2RkYmN4f2gjj2PCX4kvaAimmrLSMtgVbx4hP8W7gBkSXAzsbff3b7jfhl9DxO7UNtf8uADblYY94mXTrf7CTL5WQucnhU2rVKZfRgCh5+tJ/RagZ4aFY0e7NZi&connectionData=[{"name":"synchronizehub"}]&tid=4](http://x.xxxx.xx/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=ype2eE2RkYmN4f2gjj2PCX4kvaAimmrLSMtgVbx4hP8W7gBkSXAzsbff3b7jfhl9DxO7UNtf8uADblYY94mXTrf7CTL5WQucnhU2rVKZfRgCh5+tJ/RagZ4aFY0e7NZi&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22:%22synchronizehub%22%7D%5D&tid=4)

Can anyone help me to fix this bug.

Thank you!

I found many information from the internet but don't find any solutions for this issue

Comment: Usually, redis timeouts happen when the load is too high to be handled by the server.

Comment: @Eldar I monitored cpu of the server and cpu's usage is very low about 10-20%

Comment: That doesn't mean that your cpu’s single core is not exhausted. Redis has a single threaded architecture.